# What is the purpose of extcodecopy?

Tags: evm, bytecode

I am wondering, what is the purpose of the `EXTCODECOPY` bytecode instruction? I don't see any advantage in copying the code of another contract in memory.

I am a little bit confused, because of the existence of other instructions, such as `DELEGATECALL` that really "use" the code of another contract

Comment: One use case I can think of is validating that the code of a smart contract can be trusted.

Comment: Do you mean, something like, "I copy the code in memory, compute the hash and check if it corresponds to the sha3 version I know?"

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is used to check and compare a contract's bytecode, similar to comparing a known hash of a download file to confirm its legitimacy. The best description of why it is useful (and suggestions as to how to make it better), can be seen [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1052.md) in EIP 1052.

> Many contracts need to perform checks on a contract's bytecode, but do not necessarily need the bytecode itself. For instance, a contract may want to check if another contract's bytecode is one of a set of permitted implementations, or it may perform analyses on code and whitelist any contract with matching bytecode if the analysis passes.

Answer (score 3):

An unconventional of `EXTCODECOPY` is to use a deployed contract as the "storage" of another contract, as is is done by this library:
https://github.com/0xsequence/sstore2

The rationale is that writing/reading data in the contract code region can become cheaper than writing/reading data in the storage region.

> - Cheaper storage reads (vs SLOAD) after 32 bytes
> - Cheaper storage writes (vs SSTORE) after 32 bytes (auto-gen key)
> - Cheaper storage writes (vs SSTORE) after 96 bytes (custom key)

This [blog post](https://zefram.xyz/posts/how-i-almost-cheesed-the-evm/) from Zefram Lou has additional information about it.